# docker-compose.yml for Postgres works either way, but not the expected one

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the following docker-compose.yml for running Postgres with Docker:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_DB: mydatabasename
      PGDATA: /data/mydatabasename
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    ... placeholder

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

It works. What I don't understand, is that these two combinations work:

```
      PGDATA: /data/mydatabasename
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
```

and

```
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/mydatabasename
```

But this does not work:

```
      PGDATA: /data/mydatabasename
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/mydatabasename
```

I would just get: `error: database "mydatabasename" does not exist`.

The latter was my first attempt connecting everything though. So I am wondering, why do both fields not map to the actual database name? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The options you're adjusting at the end are filesystem paths (which usually default to `/var/lib/postgresql/data`) and don't necessarily include the database name.  In typical use I might not set `$PGDATA` at all and mount my volume at that default directory.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it seems like that it does not create the actual database when not defining PGDATA. Do I need to run any other command then for creating the actual database after `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Setting `$POSTGRES_DB` should be right.  However, the first-time initialization happens only if the database directory (the `postgres` named volume) is totally empty; if it got initialized with the wrong name you might need to delete the volume.

Answer (score 0):

#### Docker Compose File

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    posts:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data_backup:/var/lib/postgresql/data #mount the data locally 
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - postgres-net 

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres  
    netwroks:
      - postgres-net  


networks:
  postgres-net:
  name: postgres-net
```

#### .env File

```
#postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="secure_password"
POSTGRES_DB=your_db_name
POSTGRES_USER=db_user_name
#pgadmin
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=ariful@firora.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="secure_password"
PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
```

Since you may try to bind the database folder which was never created. Alternatively you can bind `/var/lib/postgresql/data` this path to store whatever database you created or about create in future.